# can not call any other function, then die my code

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm building a login with ajax and php. My code works great until I do a call in my php code to another class. when dying my php code I get int even put a var_dump. you can see in my php code I've commented it out as I want to do really

View:

```
<body>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
 <div id="content">
  <h1>Login Form</h1>
 <form id="form1" name="form1" action="stack.php"  method="post">
<p>
  <label for="username">Username: </label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</p>
<p>
  <label for="password">Password: </label>
  <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</p>
<p>
  <input type="button" id="login" name="login" value="submit"/>
   </p>
  </form>
   <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#login").click(function(){
       var action = $("#form1").attr('action');
       var form_data = {
         username: $("#username").val(),
         password: $("#password").val(), 
         is_ajax: 1
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        success: function(data){
            if(typeof(data) != 'undefined' && (data == 'success' || data == 'error')){
                if(data == 'success'){
                    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {

                        $("#message").html("<p class='success'>You have logged in
                                      successfully!</p>");
                    });
                } else if(data == 'error'){
                    $("#form1").slideUp('slow', function() {
                        $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Invalid username and/or
                         password.</p>");
                    });
                }
            } else {
                console.log("här");
                console.log(data);
                $("#message").html("<p class='error'>Error to connect to server</p>");   
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

PHP:

```
   class DologinHandler{  
    public function Login(){ 
     if(isset($_REQUEST['is_ajax']))
    {
        $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
        $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

      //  $UserHandler = new UserHandler();
        //$UserHandler -> controllDB($username,$password);
        if($username == 'demo' && $password == 'demo')
        {
            exit('success');
        } else {
            exit('error');
          }
      }
  }

 }
?>
```

Comment: What exactly happens if you call that class?

Comment: -1. Too vague. Please add info on what error you're getting. First thing that comes to mind: are you 100% sure you required the class UserHandler before you are trying to use it?

Comment: ajax actually want return "Success" and then, you're logged on. but if I just type your such a var_dump. it kills the entire code.

Comment: I must call on the user handler for where is my controill against the database. it is the one to say if it is true or false with the user. @ Pelle ten Cate

Comment: @MaxTorstensson Use `var_dump` to see your variable/array type and values. You can not use var_dump on ajax result, please let me know what do you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

If the code in your post is all the PHP code you have written, it is not going to do anything. If your client expects 'success' or 'error', the fact that it's getting an empty string may be the reason why you're getting your error message.

In PHP, when you declare a Class, the code is only executed when you instantiate that class. You can do that by adding the two lines of code Waygood wrote in his answer, to the bottom of your stack.php file.

```
<?php
/* All your PHP code */

$loginclass=new DologinHandler();
$loginclass->Login();
```

And, for good practice, if there's no content appended to the code written above, get rid of the `?>` at the bottom, that can save you quite some trouble. Not related to this issue though.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
echo 'success';
return true;
```

instead of

```
exit('success');
```

also at the end of the function you should deal with non-ajax login

stack.php should be something like:-

```
$loginclass=new DologinHandler();
$loginclass->Login();
```

Comment: I agree that is better code, but how is it related to this issue? What difference would this make? I don't see any reason why the code above shouldn't work while yours should.

Comment: don't work. i can't call another class and functions or var_dump

Comment: php is the stack.php if i set echo "success" and return true. 
I get the same error message : Error to connect to server

Comment: what do you mean where to you do login()?

Comment: Didn't read your update. If you edit your post, I'll undo the -1.